# Add custom ttitle and message to Facebook dialog share

Tags: javascript, facebook, dialog, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to share a link on Facebook, but, with a custom title and message. Let me explain, I build my url like this :

```
var obj = {
 "object":"page.html",
 "image":"image.jpg",
 "data":{
   "title":"foo",
   "message":"bar"
  }
};

var furl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share_open_graph?app_id=XXXXXXXXXX&display=popup&action_type=og.likes&action_properties=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj)) + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURI("page.html");
```

But, when I use the URL, the title and the description of the page are still the one provided by the page's meta tag and not the one I tried to defined. But, the custom image works well...

Any idea of what I could be missing ?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](http://okaypl.us/blog/facebook-share-dialog-longer-accepts-custom-parameters/) (posted on July 9, 2014), *Facebook Share Dialog No Longer Accepts Custom Parameters*...

> In the past, web developers were able to customize those elements by
> adding additional query parameters to the share dialog URL:
>
> - p[title] = Custom Title
> - p[summary] = Custom Description
> - p[images][0] = Custom Thumbnail Image

...

> All of the shared content is now pulled from the page’s Open Graph
> tags. For instance if you want to change the title or description, you
> must edit the page’s og:title or og:description meta tags,
> respectively.

I hope it helped.

Comment: correct, you now need a page with og tags for EVERYTHING you want to share.